# expression of strong feeling starting with "never"

Tags: expressions

Please, how can I express strong feeling starting with the word **never**?

Comment: This question is too vague. What kind of strong feeling?

Comment: I can't tell you how if feel because no one has ever given me such a big sum of money. how can this be reworded using "never"?

Comment: Never in my life, have I been given such a large sum of money; I’m overwhelmed.

Comment: Easy... but the sentence needs to be in the imperative. Never let them grind you down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can work for you:

`Never will I tell you how I feel because no one has ever given me such a big sum of money`

Sounds a bit biblical, but it's correct.

Comment: This sounds more like a belligerent statement. “I’ll never tell you a thing....”